# Django - Concatenated CreateView, autofill hidden input

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to make 2 CreateView (step1, step2), in first view I create a user ([djangomodels.user](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User)).

#### My step one view:

```
class UserStep1(CreateView):
    model = User
    fields = [
        'username',
        'password',
    ]

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('step-2',args=(self.object.id,))

    template_name = 'step1.html'
```

after first form submit, I redirect the user to second step form.

#### My step two view:

```
class UserStep2(CreateView):
    model = UserMeta
    fields = [
        'auth', # This is the input that I want to autocomplete with url <pk>
        'zip_code',
        'city',
    ]

    template_name = 'step2.html'
```

#### My urls:

```
url(r'^user/create/step1/$', UserStep1.as_view(), name='step-1'),
url(r'^user/create/step2/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', UserStep2.as_view(), name='step-2'),
```

#### The problem

I need to pass the user.id of first step to second step and autofill the input for 'auth' input.. how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a several steps in your forms, take a look at [FormWizard](http://django-formtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wizard.html).

It was [included in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) <= 1.7

Comment: Ok but, how can I edit the official example to works with my models? http://django-formtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wizard.html#defining-form-classes

Comment: You can override SessionWizard view http://django-formtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/wizard.html#formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.done  and take a required field from the first step